# Javascript - function return value of variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I was just doing a school project and I got a couple of forms. To try and make this more make and more cool I decided to try and automate the validation of my forms. For this I used one function to get the elements and check if they are empty and depending on this result it would return a **true** or **false**.
Depending on the outcome of this function it should decide the outcome of the other function but it simply isn't working.
My code is as follows:

```
var FormManager = {

    SubmitForm: function(elem, event){
        var $elem = $(elem);

        if(!FormManager.ValidateForm($elem)){
            switch(event){
                case 'signup':
                    var elements = $(elem).closest('form').find('input');
                    AccountManager.SignUp(elements);
                    break;
                case 'recover':
                    var email = $(elem).closest('form').find('input').val();
                    AccountManager.Recover(email);
                    break;
            }
        }
    },

    ValidateForm: function(elem){
        var main = elem.closest('form').find('input');
        var hasError = false;

        $(main).each(function(index, elem){
            var $element = $(elem);
            if($element.val() == ''){
                hasError = true;
                $element.addClass('input-error');
                $element.focus();
            }
            else{
                hasError = false;
                $element.removeClass('input-error');
            }
        });
        return hasError;
    }
};
```

So my problem is, if the user didn't write anything in the input, then the variable should return **true** and my **SubmitForm** shouldn't go through but it does.

Comment: Can you create a https://jsfiddle.net/ with your form code as well so we can see the whole picture?

Comment: `hasError` will always end up as the last value at which it was set. If *any* empty input should cause an `hasError` to be `true`, then just get rid of the `hasError = false;` line in the `.each()`.

Comment: Thank you @squint, that about did it!

Comment: You don't need jQuery to do this - you can use HTML5 and CSS.